# Scheduled SQL Server Data Export to CSV using SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server-2005, cmd, server, bcp, sqlcmd

This is my command line:

```
sqlcmd -S DEVSERVER\SQLEXPRESS -i  c:\SQL_Query.sql -o c:\CSV_Output.csv -s”,”
```

And my sql script:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.pay
```

The file with this error message:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server DEVSERVER\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.pay'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify database name.

`sqlcmd -S [sql server name] –d [database name] –U [user name] –P [password] –Q "your sql query" –s "," –o "D:\demo.csv"`

Comment: sqlcmd -S DEVSERVER\SQLEXPRESS –d AWP_WWW –U dbadmin –P Admin123$  –Q ”SELECT * FROM dbo.pay –s “,” –o “C:\export-sql-server-to-csv\output.txt”

Comment: this is my command line, when i execute it it shows "Unexpected Arguement" in cmd. Need help thx.

Comment: Can you try with file name output.CSV?

Comment: It is because of double quotes(copy & paste). Can you type the double quotes manually and try?

Comment: Thanks Imran, i typed the double quotes manually and i able to fixed the problem. But when i add " WHERE st_code='abc' , 'abc1' ; " statement, it appears the same problem again.

Comment: The condition should be "WHERE st_code IN ('abc','abc1')".